# boost::shared_ptr - composition relation between two classes

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

Suppose that I have:

- two classes: P and C.
- composition relations between P <>- C, i.e. every instance of P contains an instance of C, which is destroyed when the parent P instance is destroyed.

To implement this, in C++ I:

- define two classes P and C;
- define a member variables of P of type boost::shared_ptr, and initialize it with a newly created object in P's constructor.

A code example is given below.

```
    #include "boost/scoped_ptr.hpp"

    class C
    {
      public:
        C() {}

      private:

    };

    class P
    {
      public:
        P() : childC(new C()) {}

      private:
        boost::shared_ptr<C> childC;
    };

    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        P p;
    }
```

Somehow I can't build this simple code example, and I don't get why (I'm a novice to programming).

Errors:

> class ‘P’ does not have any field named ‘childC’
>
> expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
>
> invalid use of ‘::’
>
> ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘shared_ptr’ with no type

Comment: If you want a `shared_ptr` then you need to `#include "boost/shared_ptr.hpp"`. But why would it need to be shared?

Comment: "scoped", "shared", ...

Comment: Yet another novel and strained application of the "parent/child" metaphor.

Comment: Thanks guys, I made a serious mistake.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I want to use boost::shared_ptr's to minimize the chance of generating memory leakage (So I don't have to destruct all child objects explicitly).

Comment: @JackTuyp You don't, unless you want to *share* each instance with others. That isn't clear from your question.

Comment: In fact, it isn't clear you need a pointer at all. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely cause of your errors is that you are including `boost/scoped_ptr.hpp` and you are trying to declare a `boost::shared_ptr`. It is unlikely you need a `boost::shared_ptr` here.

The simplest way to express [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) in this case would be

```
class C {};
class P 
{
 private:
  C c_;
};
```

Now you may want to reduce compile time dependencies by using an idiom that requires only a forward declaration of `C`, in which case `P`'s header could be

```
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>

class C; // forward declaration

class P
{
 public:
  P() : c_(new C()) {}
 private:
  boost::scoped_ptr<C> c_;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As KerrekSB has hinted in the comments, you have used `shared_ptr`, but included `scoped_ptr`. The difference is that the `scoped_ptr` expresses exclusive ownership (which is the case here), while `shared_ptr` expresses shared ownership (which is not the case). The preferred idiom is to use `scoped_ptr` in the code.

If you absolutely want to use shared_ptr, include the header `<boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp>`.